# How to find the last step required for finding the Maximum Likelihood Estimator?

Tags: statistics

We have a bernoulli distribution and we are trying to find an estimator for  $p$.

Here is the bernoulli formula $p\left( x_{i}\right) =p^{x}\left( 1-p\right) ^{1-x},x=0,1$

The joint probability mass function is given by doing
$$\begin{aligned}f\left( x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n}\right | p) =p^{x_{1}}\left( 1-p\right) ^{1-x_{i}}\ldots p^{x_{n}}\left( 1-p\right) ^{1-x_{n}}\\
=p^{\sum ^{n}_{1}x_{i}}\left( 1-p\right) ^{n-\sum ^{n}x_{i}},x_{i}=0,1\end{aligned} $$

We take the logs to obtain:
$$ \log f\left( x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n}\right |p) =\sum ^{n}_{1}x_{i}\log p+\left( n-\sum ^{n}_{1}x_{i}\right) \log \left( 1-p\right) $$

We then differentiate:
$$ \dfrac {d}{dp}\log f\left( x_{i},\ldots ,x_{n}\right | p) =\dfrac {\sum ^{n}_{1}x_{i}}{p}-\dfrac {\left( n-\sum ^{n}_{1}x_{i}\right) }{1-p}$$

Upon equating to 0 and solving we obtain:
$$ \dfrac {\sum ^{n}_{1}x_{i}}{\widehat {p}}=\dfrac {n-\sum ^{n}_{1}x_{i}}{1-\widehat {p}}$$

now I want to understand how we arrive to :
$$\widehat {p}=\dfrac {\sum ^{n}_{i=1}x_{i}}{n}$$

Comment: This maybe related:https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/191/

Comment: @NoChance In the link you gave me why do we multiply through by p(1−p)?

Comment: Because it is the common denominator.

Comment: Oh, yeah how come I didn't see that... thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point it is high school algebra to solve for $\hat{p}$. Since $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ iff $ad=bc$ we are left with
$$
(1-\hat{p})\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=(n-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)\hat{p}
$$
or multiplying out that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=n\hat{p}
$$
from which the desired claim follows.

Answer (score 0):

It's basic algebra.  For simplicity I am going to set $A= \sum_1^n x_i$.  So your first equation is $\frac{A}{p}= \frac{n-A}{1- p}$.  Multiply both sides by p(1- p) to get $A(1- p)= (n- A)p$.  Then $A- pA= np- pA$.  $A= np$ so $p= \frac{A}{n}$.